# How to create a new meta-formalism?

Tags: emf, metamodel, mda

I'm newbie with the using of EMF.
I understand the theory of MDA and MDD, and does some practice using Atom3 and AtomPM.
I know how to create a meta-model and meta-formalism (meta-meta-model) and how to create transformation rules using the two previous tools.
So, i need to know how to create a new meta-formalism(meta-meta-model) using EMF and how to create a meta-model using it. and how to create a model using the new meta-model.
Think you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get started from this Vogella article (for example):

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEMF/article.html